# How to import * as an alias in python?

Tags: python, import

How to `import *` as an alias in python?

If I do `from scapy.all import * as scmodule`, it gives me an invalid syntax.

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Answer (score 2):

Its because you cant import all methods with same name.
your code means that you are importing all methods with same name!!! so that is impossible.

you use ***as*** for only one method.

```
from keras import backend as K
```

when you use * you can only call methods with their **original** name.

```
from keras.models import *
""" Model and Input are from keras library"""
model = Model() #example
input = Input()
```